# Display HTML coming from database as if it was typed in a wysiwyg editor

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to display some basic HTML code coming from database in a part of an angular application.

I've investigated and know that you shouldn't do that and it can pose security risks, but I got to thinking and I know that you can usually install a WYSIWYG editor and fill it after the query loads, but I would like to try to avoid installing something like that.

Comment: Have you tried giving it to `innerText` or `innerHtml` of an html elemet?
e.g: if it's a text give it to i`nnerText` of `<p>` and some html element, then you gave give it to `innerHtml` of a `div`.

Comment: I was trying that right now, but it appears as [object HTMLSpanElement]